# How is this implied by the properties of the exponential, gamma, and $\chi^2$ distributions?

Tags: gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, degrees-of-freedom, chi-squared-distribution, exponential-family

Let's say we have the random variables $X_1, \dots, X_p$. Furthermore, say that these random variables are a random sample from a PDF of the form

$$f_\tau (x) =
\begin{cases}
 \tau x^{\tau-1}, & 0 < x < 1, \tau > 0 \\
      0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Now define $Y_i = - \log(X_i)$. If I'm not mistaken, this means that $Y_i$ has an exponential distribution.

I am then told that

$$E \left[ \dfrac{1}{2 \tau \Sigma_{i = 1}^p Y_i} \right] = \dfrac{1}{2(p - 1)}$$

and

$$\text{Var} \left( \dfrac{1}{2 \tau \Sigma_{i = 1}^p Y_i} \right) = \dfrac{1}{4(p - 1)^2(p - 2)}$$

Apparently, this is implied by the properties of the exponential, gamma, and $\chi^2$ distributions. However, I have no idea how this is the case. Trying to 'fill in the blanks' here, the denominators $2(p - 1)$ and $4(p - 1)^2(p - 2)$ look like something you'd get related to the DOF for a $\chi^2$ random variable, but, as I said, so much information is left out here that I can't follow the reasoning. How are these results implied by the properties of the exponential, gamma, and $\chi^2$ distributions? What exactly is the reasoning used here?

Comment: You are provided complete information about this situation--nothing is left out.  There are many ways to derive these results.  One useful starting point might be to determine the expectation and variance of the [Inverse Gamma distribution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution)  You then only need to know that sums of *iid* Exponential variables have Gamma distributions.

Comment: @whuber Hmm, how does the inverse gamma distribution relate to this?

Comment: Given that the $\chi^2$ distribution is a special case of Gamma distribution, you can focus on Gammas only.

Comment: @ThePointer Do you know the distribution of $\sum_i Y_i$ or its inverse?

Comment: I have no idea what you're all talking about. This is why I wanted a more detailed answer.

Comment: Consider [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=exponential+gamma+chi) for appropriate information, then.

Comment: @user257566 I think it has a $\chi^2$, right? At least, that seems to agree with my suspicion (see what I said regarding the denominators).

Comment: @ThePointer A clear path forward would be to investigate what happens when you sum up independent exponential distributions. You should google around and search the site for that. That tells you about $\sum_i Y_i$. Then, what happens when you invert that distribution? Is it possible to readily find its first two moments? In each case, the answers are taught in introductory probability courses and can be readily found online. Exploring online will probably be helpful to develop connections between distributions.

Comment: @user257566 That makes sense. I'll do further research and see what I find.

Comment: Discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133843/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/335087/119261.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes, that looks helpful. Thanks!