# Statistical Inference Casella & Berger Exercise 7.11

Tags: maximum-likelihood, inference, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution

I'm self studying statistics using Casella & Berger Statistical Inference and I'm confused about a detail in solution to exercise 7.11.

Here's the problem I'm try to solve:

> Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be iid with pdf
>
> $$ f(x|\theta) = \theta x ^ {\theta - 1}, 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 < \theta < \infty $$
>
> Find the MLE of $\theta$ and show that its variance $ \rightarrow 0 $
> as $ n \rightarrow \infty $.

So far, I've been able to do the calculus to obtain MLE candidate $ \hat{\theta} = - \frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} log(x_i)} $ and prove that it is indeed a maximum.

However, I'm stuck at the point of trying to model the distribution of the parameter $\theta$ so that I can calculate the variance of the distribution to prove that it approaches 0.

In the solution, it states:

> To calculate the variance of $\hat{\theta}$, note that $Y_i = -log X_i \sim \text{exponential}(1/\theta)$ so $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} log(X_i) \sim \text{gamma}(n, 1/\theta) $.

I understand that the sum of $n$ i.i.d exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$ is equal to gamma random variable with distribution parameters $(n, \lambda)$; however, I do not understand how they initially determined that $log X_i \sim \text{exponential}(1/\theta)$.

So far I've tried taking the log of the pdf, however, when doing this, this doesn't resemble a gamma distribution with parameter $1/\theta$.

Can anyone offer some insight into this?

Comment: Hint: The pdf of the log transform is not the log of the pdf.

Comment: Hint (2): Check [the change of variable or Jacobian formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Function_of_random_variables_and_change_of_variables_in_the_probability_density_function)

Comment: A search for the key words ["log," "uniform," "exponential"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=log*+uniform+exponential+distribution) turns up many answers here on CV.

Comment: Ahhh okay I see. Thank you for the hint @Xi'an!

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133843/119261, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/335087/119261